# $|f'(x)| \le M$ on $[a,b]$ $\implies$ $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> **Problem:** Let $f$ be differentiable on $[a,b]$.  Assuming that there exists $M$
>   such that $|f'(x)| \le M$ for each $x \in [a,b]$, prove that $f$ is of
>   bounded variation on that interval.  (Hint: remember the mean value
>   theorem?)

1. Let $T_a^b$ denote the total variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$.  That is, we have

   $$
   T_a^b = \sup \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n \left| f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1}) \right|\right\} \text{ across all subdivisions of $[a,b]$}
   $$
2. Recall that the mean value theorem states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then $\exists c \in (a,b)$ s.t.

   $$
   f'(c) = {f(b) - f(a) \over b - a}
   $$
3. Then notice that our hypothesis satisfies the condition of the mean value theorem, so that the equality above holds in our setting.
4. Yet we can also say that

   $$
   |f'(c)| = \left| {f(b) - f(a) \over b -a} \right| \le M
   $$

   so that also

   $$
   |f'(c)||b - a| = \left| {f(b) - f(a)} \right| \le M|b-a|
   $$

   given our hypothesis.

There's a lot of structural similarity between the expression in (4) and the definition of $T_a^b$ in (1), so I feel like I'm on the cusp of the answer.

Comment: Why apply the MVT once, to the interval $[a,b]$, when you can apply it many times (to the subintervals)? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extremely close to having the answer! Just observe $$\sum_{k=1}^n |f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| \le M \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k - x_{k-1}| = M(b-a)$$
because
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k - x_{k-1}| = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k - x_{k-1} = b-a.$$

Comment: What justifies the inequality statement you made?  Isn't it true that $\sum_{k=1}^n |f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| \ge |f(b)-f(a)|$, and how doesn't that invalidate the inequality reasoning that you and Pedro are employing above.

Comment: On step 4 of your answer you can use the mean value theorem on each interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ instead of the full interval $[a,b]$. For each $k$ there exists $c_k \in (x_{k-1},x_k)$ with the property that $f'(c_k)(x_k - x_{k-1}) = f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})$.

Answer (score 2):

Using your work, for any partition $P=\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left| f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1}) \right|\leqslant M\sum_{k=1}^n \left| x_i - x_{i-1} \right|=M(b-a)$$